# playing random new video when refreshing page

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I am trying to make a website with only one video displayed (covering the whole page because it's supposed to be opened with a phone). But when refreshing the page a random new video appears. I have 8 mp4 videos (with a dropbox link) and Im trying to get the video to randomise between these 8 videos when refreshing the page. I hope this makes sense.

Here is what I have done so far - it's not working unfortunately

I think it might have to do with the url I am using.

**HTML:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="function.js"></script>
<title>untitled page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <video id="videoItem">
    <source src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/s7nfpv6g65gjumc/film%202.mp4?raw=1" type="video/mp4" />
 
</video>
</body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
// JavaScript Document
document.getElementById(videopage)
<script> 
function getRandomInt(min, max) {         
return Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length);
    target = document.getElementById('videoItem');
     var sources = video.getElementsByTagName('source');
     var videoUrl=["https://www.dropbox.com/s/s7nfpv6g65gjumc/film%202.mp4?raw=1", "https://www.dropbox.com/s/qnmb9s5b0vho328/film%203.mp4?raw=1", "https://www.dropbox.com/s/ey4a07703h8henq/film%205.mp4?raw=1", "https://www.dropbox.com/s/et157quhjel6mcu/film%206.mp4?raw=1", "https://www.dropbox.com/s/e0nrb47fetotcsw/film%207.mp4?raw=1", "https://www.dropbox.com/s/npj70zhxzecs4lp/film%208.mp4?raw=1"];
     var random_nr = getRandomInt(0, videoUrlsMp4.length-1);
     sources[0].src = videoUrlsMp4[random_nr ];
     video.load(); </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is a minimal implementation that loads a new video on every page load.

Note that you do not need a `<source>`-element, instead the shown solution adds a `src`-attribute to the `<video>`-element itself.

Also note that I have added the `muted` and `playsinline` attributes to the `<video>`-element, otherwise mobile clients may/will refuse to play the video since loading it wasn't triggered by a user gesture.

```js
var videoEl = document.querySelector('#videoItem');

var videoUrls = [
  "https://www.dropbox.com/s/s7nfpv6g65gjumc/film%202.mp4?raw=1", 
  "https://www.dropbox.com/s/qnmb9s5b0vho328/film%203.mp4?raw=1", 
  "https://www.dropbox.com/s/ey4a07703h8henq/film%205.mp4?raw=1", 
  "https://www.dropbox.com/s/et157quhjel6mcu/film%206.mp4?raw=1", 
  "https://www.dropbox.com/s/e0nrb47fetotcsw/film%207.mp4?raw=1", 
  "https://www.dropbox.com/s/npj70zhxzecs4lp/film%208.mp4?raw=1"
];


videoEl.addEventListener('canplay', function () {
  videoEl.play();
});

videoEl.src = videoUrls[Math.floor(Math.random() * videoUrls.length)];
```

```html
<video id="videoItem" src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/s7nfpv6g65gjumc/film%202.mp4?raw=1" muted playsinline>
</video>
```